# How to read artifactory's artifact properties in gradle build script

Tags: jenkins, gradle, properties, artifactory

I have 2 jenkins jobs, the first job publishes a jar file to artifactory and add a property (commit id) to the artifact. The second job always pulls the latest version jar from artifactory but it also requires the property associated with that artifact. We are using gradle for our builds. Is there a way to get it inside gradle or do we have any other alternative?

Edit: The jobs are not part of the pipeline. Meaning they are independent jobs and the second job triggers on another repository change.

Answer (score 0):

First jenkins job triggers second parameterized build.

The second build can trigger gradle one of two ways, using the `Invoke Gradle script` or by command line.

If you are using the `Invoke Gradle script` feature then you would check `Pass job parameters as Gradle properties`.  Then assuming your parameter for build two is named `commitId` you could reference this in your code like this

```
if (project.properties.containsKey('commitId')) {
    println "do something with commitId: ${project.properties.get('commitId')}"
}
```

If your just using a command line script then you can pass properties like this

`./gradlew clean build -PcommitId=${commitId}`

Either way to get the properties inside the `build.gradle` is the same

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an edit to my answer. 
My 2 jobs are independent jobs and I dont want to trigger the second job every time my first job runs and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Artifactory client](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java) (Java) in order to get the artifact properties.
For example:

```
Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClient.create("http://localhost:8081/artifactory", "username", "password");
ItemHandle item = artifactory.repository("RepoName").file("path/to/file.jar");
List<String> values = item.getPropertyValues("commitId");
```

For more information about the client see its GitHub [page](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java).